# Armazenar múltiplos valores na mesma coluna do banco de dados, até onde isso vale a pena?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

Percebo que muitas pessoas esbarram nesta dúvida em algum momento do desenvolvimento, "Coloco os valores separados por vírgula na mesma coluna? Ou crio um tabela auxiliar?", ambos os questionamentos possuem seus pontos a se analisar.

> Gostaria de utilizar este post, para gerar um conteúdo que venha agregar não só ao meu conhecimento, mas também no estudo de diversas pessoas que em algum momento se deparou, ou irá se deparar com está situação.

A criação de uma tabela auxiliar, possui algumas vantagens no tratamento e organização dos dados, mas de certo modo acaba ocupando mais espaço no BD quando o fluxo de informação passa a crescer.

A utilização de múltiplos valores na mesma coluna, creio eu que gera uma economia de espaço, mas por outro lado, acaba tornando o SQL mais complexo e os dados mais difíceis de tratar. Qual seria o modelo mais interessante a se seguir, quando nos deparamos em uma situação como essa?

Comment: Você quer saber especificamente de MySQL com PHP? Ou é uma pergunta mais geral para bancos de dados relacionais?

Comment: Olá Jefferson, a questão é voltada ao banco de dados, farei a remoção do PHP das tags para não confundir.

Answer (score 1):

Tudo depende da quantidade de informação que pretende armazenar numa só coluna e o que pretende, em última análise, fazer com ela. Se for apenas alguns valores, poderá valer a pena, visto que o espaço que irá ocupar na base de dados e o "trabalho" para partir a string, tratá-la e compreendê-la será mínimo.

Mas se a sua coluna for do tipo `TEXT` ou `NTEXT` (ou mesmo `VARCHAR(MAX)`) e armazenar muita informação (separada sim, mas muita na mesma) poderá (quase de certeza) ter problemas de *performance* nas consultas onde incluir essa coluna (a criação de índices poderá ser um problema), além do que será bem mais difícil perceber o conteúdo da informação e, por vezes, bem difícil de tratar a informação (o trocar de um índice pode ter efeitos indesejados no código!).

Na minha opinião é sempre melhor criar novas tabelas, normalizar a informação e utilizar o SQL corretamente para ligar a informação na forma de chaves, além de ser uma prática bem mais "correta".

Answer (score 0):

Concordo em partes com a opinião do nosso colega João Martins.
Geralmente utilizo desta funcionalidade em minhas soluções, e me baseio no seguinte critério para decidir entre criar uma nova tabela ou armazenar os dados em uma simples coluna:

**- Caso 1 - Criação de uma coluna e armazenamento separado por caractere curinga** 
Informação simples (não multi-valorado)

Ex.: Para uma tabela onde armazeno as MDF-e ([Manifesto de Documentos Fiscais Eletrônicos](https://mdfe-portal.sefaz.rs.gov.br/)) emitidas. Uma das exigências deste documento fiscal eletrônico é uma sequencia de tags denomidada  - "Lacres das Unidades de Transporte". Tal informação trata-se de uma sequência simples de strings (uma tag denomidada  - "Número do lacre"), em que não preciso fazer consultas (clausa WHERE do SQL) nem algum tipo de relacionamento (JOINS). Ou seja, só utilizo para mostrar em uma grade na tela e posteriormente para gerar o XML do MDF-e.

Resultado:

**No banco armazeno assim: "123#456##789#..."**

**Ao gerar o xml ficaria assim:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**- Caso 2 - Criação de uma nova tabela com chave estrangeira e demais dados necessários**
Decido pela criação de uma nova tabela, quando a situação é contrária ao exemplo do Caso 1. Ou seja, os dados são multi-valorados e preciso fazer consultas e joins no futuro.

Ex.: Continuando com o caso de uso do MDF-e. Um outro requisito deste DF-e é a geração de um conjunto de tags, denominadas  - "Dados do CIOT".
Neste caso, este agrupamentos de tags, possui em seu interior um grupo de informações específicas - Diferentemente do Caso 1, onde só existia uma sequência simples de dados ()

Resultado:
**No banco, criaria a uma tabela: "MDFeInfCIOT":**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Ao gerar o xml ficaria assim:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]